# Indented Word Wrap in LaTeX

Tags: text, latex, typesetting

I'm writing a document in LaTeX, and am encountering a problem when I have a line of text that wraps around. What I need is for the text, when it wraps around, to indent so that it matches the label (much like the \item[Label:] Text function, except I can't use a {description} context. Any ideas?

This happens in the context of

```
\newcommand{\objectiveresheading}[1]{%
  {\parashade[.9]{sharpcorners{\textbf{\Large{Objective: }\large{#1}}}}}
```

Comment: probably gonna need more information-- are you inside an environment of any type? or is this occurring in the body text?

Comment: It is contained within this defined function: \newcommand{\objectiveresheading}[1]{{\parashade[.9]{sharpcorners}{\textbf{\Large{Objective: }\large{#1}}}}}

\objectiveresheading is called within the body text.

Comment: Ouch. Please don't put that much code in a comment...edit the question instead. The control is right under the tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an internal LaTeX macro to perform this function called `\@hangfrom`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\objectiveresheading[1]{%
  \@hangfrom{\Large\bfseries Objective: }%
  {\large\bfseries #1\par}%
} 
\makeatother
\objectiveresheading{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

Note that the wrapped text can only be a single paragraph. If you need multiple paragraphs, something more similar to a list environment would be better.

Comment: How do you discover stuff like this?  Browsing `latex.ltx`?

Comment: Osmosis :) I haven't spent much time reading source2e cover-to-cover, so to speak, but I've spent a fair amount of time in various sections of it. Otherwise, spending lots of time in places like comp.tex.text., where there's a bunch of people who've been using (La)TeX for decades longer than I.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the label into a numbered box, take the width of that box, and use `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` to make an indented paragraph.  To learn how to use `\setbox`, `\wd`, `\hangindent`, and `\hangafter`, the best source is probably the horse's mouth: *The TeXbook*.

Comment: Yep, this is what `\@hangfrom` does internally :)

Comment: I'd say it's more important to know how to do it! But for a question like this it's useful to know a shortcut. P.S. One day I may well solicit you for noweb expertise :)